# Why is it looking for formats ... and where are they? (SAS)

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I'm trying to run a macro (mcartest). Here is the beginning of the code (full code is [here](https://communities.sas.com/kntur85557/attachments/kntur85557/programming/162574/1/Little%20Code.pdf), although I modified it to allow entering options in the macro call):

```
macro mcartest (data=,items=);
/* PROVIDE VALUES FOR THE FOLLOWING MACRO VARIABLES */
%let datafile = &data; * dataset to be analyzed;
%let numvars = %sysfunc(countw(&items));
%let misscode = .; * SPECIFY MISSING VALUE CODE;
%let varnames = &items; * SPECIFY VARIABLE NAMES;
%let seednum = 564321; * SPECIFY RANDOM SEED;
/* DO NOT ALTER THE CODE BELOW */
data one;
set &datafile ;

array m[&numvars] &varnames ; array r[&numvars] r1 - r&numvars ;
do i = 1 to &numvars;
if m[i] = &misscode then m[i] = .;
end; drop i;
do i = 1 to &numvars;
r[i] = 1;
if m[i] = . then r[i] = 0;
end; drop i;

proc sort;
by r1-r&numvars;

...
```

When SAS is creating the dataset ONE, it seems to be looking for formats, but I don't know why it is looking for that. When would a format library have been created. Here is part of the LOG file:

```
MPRINT(MCARTEST):   data one;
MPRINT(MCARTEST):   set nicole.rawdatarecoded ;
MPRINT(MCARTEST):   array m[74] LASSI1 LASSI2 LASSI3 LASSI4 LASSI5 LASSI6 LASSI7 LASSI8 LASSI9
LASSI10 LASSI11 LASSI12 LASSI13 LASSI14 LASSI15 LASSI16 LASSI17 LASSI18 LASSI19 LASSI20 LASSI21
LASSI22 LASSI23 LASSI24 LASSI25 LASSI26 LASSI27 LASSI28 LASSI29 LASSI30 LASSI31 LASSI32 LASSI33
LASSI34 LASSI35 LASSI36 SWLS_1 SWLS_2 SWLS_3 SWLS_4 SWLS_5 ISEL1 ISEL2 ISEL3 ISEL4 ISEL5 ISEL6
ISEL7 ISEL8 ISEL9 ISEL10 ISEL11 ISEL12 DASS1 DASS2 DASS3 DASS4 DASS5 DASS6 DASS7 DASS8 DASS9
DASS10 DASS11 DASS12 DASS13 DASS14 DASS15 DASS16 DASS17 DASS18 DASS19 DASS20 DASS21 ;
MPRINT(MCARTEST):   array r[74] r1 - r74 ;
MPRINT(MCARTEST):   do i = 1 to 74;
MPRINT(MCARTEST):   if m[i] = . then m[i] = .;
MPRINT(MCARTEST):   end;
MPRINT(MCARTEST):   drop i;
MPRINT(MCARTEST):   do i = 1 to 74;
MPRINT(MCARTEST):   r[i] = 1;
MPRINT(MCARTEST):   if m[i] = . then r[i] = 0;
MPRINT(MCARTEST):   end;
MPRINT(MCARTEST):   drop i;

ERROR: Width specified for format F is invalid.
NOTE: Format STATUSA was not found or could not be loaded.
ERROR: Width specified for format F is invalid.
ERROR: Width specified for format F is invalid.
NOTE: Format FINISHEA was not found or could not be loaded.
NOTE: Format CONSENTA was not found or could not be loaded.
NOTE: Format AGEA was not found or could not be loaded.
NOTE: Format YEAR_INA was not found or could not be loaded.
NOTE: Format RACE_ETA was not found or could not be loaded.
NOTE: Format GENDER_A was not found or could not be loaded.
NOTE: Format ISEL12_A was not found or could not be loaded.
NOTE: Format ISEL121A was not found or could not be loaded.
NOTE: Format ISEL122A was not found or could not be loaded.
NOTE: Format ISEL123A was not found or could not be loaded.
NOTE: Format ISEL124A was not found or could not be loaded.
NOTE: Format ISEL125A was not found or could not be loaded.
NOTE: Format ISEL126A was not found or could not be loaded.
*and so on for all the variables.*
```

Comment: What do you get if you submit the following code outside of the macro? `data demo; set nicole.rawdatarecoded;run;`

Comment: Interesting.. This code creates the same errors.

Comment: I just don't understand why SAS is looking for formats, and where they would be and why the catalog wouldn't be in an obvious place.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with the macro processor.

From the SAS LOG your code is creating `ONE` by reading in `nicole.rawdatarecoded` .  So the formats are attached to the variables in that dataset.

To know where to find those formats you need to ask the person that created that dataset where they stored the formats.  Once you know what catalog (or catalogs) contain the formats you can add those to the setting of the FMTSEARCH system option to tell SAS where to look for the formats.  Then it should be able to find them.

Comment: I created this data set in SPSS, and then imported it into SAS. What I don't get is that there are no format catalog showing up anywhere... not in the Nicole library and not in the Work library. 

Why would it be expecting formats if I haven't created any? Is it getting it from the SPSS data set? Where would they be?

Comment: You need to tell PROC IMPORT where to write the formats it creates from the value labels in the SPSS file.  You should probably write the format catalog into the same library as you wrote the data since WORK files are deleted when the session ends.

Answer (score 0):

When you create the data set with SPSS, it will also create a .SAS file with the format definitions. You need to run that code before this to create the formats.

Otherwise, to use the 'raw' data you can set the option below:

`options nofmterror;`

However, that means if you had coded 1=Blue and 2=Green, then it will show up as 1/2 not Blue/Green in your data. I believe the equivalent of formats in SAS is Value Labels in SPSS. So your SPSS data has a bunch of Value Labels attached to each variable.

Answer (score -1):

Well... I didn't exactly figure out the problem, but I got the error to go away by creating a new dataset (data; set nicole.rawdatarecoded (keep = ...);).

Comment: That is doing the same thing your original code did.  The only difference is you are only keeping some of the variables.  Perhaps you just did not keep the variables that had unknown formats attached to them.  That would stop you from getting that message.  Otherwise you did something else that made it so SAS knew where to find the formats.